# What is term for a brand identity "color treatment"?

Tags: logo, branding, identity

What is the industry standard term for a set of color guidelines for a brand identity?

- Logo Usage Guidelines
- Brand Identity Guidelines
- Something else?

Edit:

As Scott mentioned "whatever works". There does not seem to be any strict term, however searching for "brand guideline", "brand guide", or "brand style guide" appears to produce the most authoritative results. Substituting "Identity" for "Guide" will also yield good results.

It should be mentioned that these guides do far more than dictate color usage, I highly recommend reading some samples for anyone who is interested. For examples check out this list: http://www.logodesignlove.com/brand-identity-style-guides

Comment: Related: [How do you call “Charte Graphique” in English?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/17486/8708)

Comment: It's typically the 'color' section/chapter of the 'corporate brand/identity standards' document.

Comment: Colour guidelines normally boil down to being called the *palette* but you appear to be asking about two different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever works.

Brand Guidelines is the one I use and see most often. The identity is merely part of the brand.

Comment: I'm looking for some keywords to search for, so far I'm seeing "styleguide", "brand identity", "style guidelines", "corporate identity guidelines", in all combinations.

Comment: Style guides generally refer to web design. Brand Guidelines refer to the corporate brand in any media.

Comment: Why would Style Guide only be for web? I used to write corporate guidelines and I've never seen that distinction.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum Often a Style Guide can refer to CSS definitions for a web site - a la Cascading **Style** Sheets. When I see a "Style Guide" it's markedly different than "Brand Guidelines". Brand Guidelines can include Style Guidelines, but the reverse is rarely true from what I've seen.

Comment: Okay, I believe you; that's just completely outside my experience.

Answer (score 0):

I'd search for "corporate color palette" or "corporate colors."